# Even spacing on each side of responsive container

Tags: containers, center, spacing

Consider the following layout:
http://jsfiddle.net/W74Z8/113/

How do I get even spacing (5% on the left and right) on left and right side of the container so it's in perfectly horizontally centered (and in all of the media queries)?

I've tried to manually do the % so it's fits but I can't get it working. Do you have any ideas?

I did a post and illustration earlier explaining what I want to do. Maybe it will help:
http://itu.dk/people/mbul/portfolio/problem_portfolio.jpg

```
<div class="container">

<ul>
    <li><img src="http://itu.dk/people/mbul/portfolio/box.png"></img></li>  
    <li><img src="http://itu.dk/people/mbul/portfolio/box.png"></img></li>    
    <li><img src="http://itu.dk/people/mbul/portfolio/box.png"></img></li>
    <li><img src="http://itu.dk/people/mbul/portfolio/box.png"></img></li>   
    <li><img src="http://itu.dk/people/mbul/portfolio/box.png"></img></li>   
    <li><img src="http://itu.dk/people/mbul/portfolio/box.png"></img></li>
</ul>    

</div>


ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left:2%;
    padding-right: 1%;
    }

img {
    width: 23%; 
    float: left; 
    margin-right: 1%;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
    }


@media only screen and (max-width : 1250px) {
/*row of three boxes*/

    img {
    width: 31%; 
    float: left; 
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 1000px) {
/*row of two boxes*/

    img {
    width: 46%; 
    float: left; 
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 670px) {
/*row of one boxes*/

.container {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left:0em;
    padding-right: 0em;
    }    

img {
    width: 100%; 
    float: none; 
    margin-right: 0em;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be able to just use margin: auto. So what you are looking at is (CSS):

```
.container-example {
   width: 50%;
   margin: auto;
}
```

And the div in your page:

```
<div class="container-example"></div>
```

That should do it. See a JSFiddle here (http://jsfiddle.net/wwwbv/)!

*Note* - The only thing you should need to change for responsive is the width in your media examples. You can use either a width in pixels or a width in percents, either will work well. Good luck!